# XLOOKUP [match_mode] when applying multiple criteria

Tags: xlookup

I have a table that's formatted something like this

| Var 1 | Var 2 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 100 | 123 |
| 100 | 200 | 456 |
| 100 | 300 | 789 |
| 200 | 100 | 012 |
| 200 | 200 | 345 |
| 200 | 300 | 678 |
| 300 | 100 | 901 |
| 300 | 200 | 234 |
| 300 | 300 | 567 |

I need to fin a result based on both variables. I know about XLOOKUP(1, (criteria1)*(criteria2)) general format but I'm wondering if there is still a way to incorporate the XLOOKUP [match_mode] arguments such as exact or next smaller item, or similar. I tried stuff like XLOOKUP(1, (criterion1)*(criterion2),,-1,) but it didn't work. Also, I may want to apply different [match mode] flags for different variables. I couldn't find anything online. Thanks.